# MySQL as key-value ordered store

Tags: mysql, key-value

[Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) say that:

> Most MySQL indexes (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT) are stored in B-trees.

So physically the data is already sorted by key. I need a key-value scheme in MySQL with range query support:

`SELECT key, value FROM MyTable WHERE key >= key1 and key < key2;`

In many (majority) examples on the web I see that people add `ORDER BY` even when selecting by the primary key.

My questions:

- Is ORDER BY really needed here to get the results always sorted, and if yes - why?
- Will sorting affect performance or it will be optimized away?
- Will it make sense to make values a part of composite index if they are not too big, e.g. just numbers?
- Will `SELECT key, value FROM MyTable WHERE key > key1 LIMIT 1;` return the next key greater then key1, or any key greater than key1? How to reliably get LT,LE,GT,GE point queries?

(I need it in MySQL for near 'political' and tooling reasons before moving to other existing B+-tree based KV storage, I have already picked the best one LMDB, so the questions are only about mocking the scheme in MySQL)

Comment: If it's on the web, it has to be true ;)

Comment: @nomistic Sarcasm? :) After googling and seeing many examples I really need some sanity check

Comment: I'm not an expert here, so I'm going to avoid actually answering the question, but applying order by should always have a neutral or negative effect on this query. On an unindexed column, best case sort is always O(n log n), while actually checking every record with a full table scan will be O(n). On an indexed column stored in a B-Tree, sorting would have no effect if it used the same comparison operator, and a negative effect if it used a different one.

Comment: yes, sorry.   My understanding for the first part is that it done by habit and good coding practice (it does make sense if it is not the primary key). Also, sometimes the primary key is not numerical (such as a type_code type of variable... I use these a lot for table with some level of control to speed up the ease of querying, but in that case I will usually order by the value, and not the code).   I will sometimes order by two entries.  Sorry, I don't know about performance, but my guess is that it is minimal.   No idea about the last part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- > Is ORDER BY really needed here to get the results always sorted, and if yes - why?

  Without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL *might* happen to return results in the desired order—but such behaviour *is not guaranteed* and cannot be relied upon (there could be edge cases that break the behaviour, or it may change unexpectedly in a future release without any warning).

  Since you **need** the resultset always to be sorted, you *must* add an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.
- > Will sorting affect performance or it will be optimized away?

  If you have a *covering* index—i.e. one defined over the composite `(key, value)`—then the exact query mentioned in your question will be able to retrieve sorted records directly from that index.  MySQL need merely walk the B-tree data structure, locate the desired range of results, and return what it finds.

  If you do not have a covering index, then once MySQL has located the `key` values that fall within the filtered range (using the index), it must then seek into the table itself to retrieve each associated `value`.  Since it is faster to perform this operation in disk order (to minimise IO thrashing), MySQL probably *will not* use the index for sorting, but will instead perform a filesort on the results.  I say "probably" because the optimiser may make different decisions in some edge cases, depending on things like table size, index cardinality and/or storage engine.

  You can always [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html) your queries to view the execution plan that the optimiser has decided upon, and in particular whether a filesort will be performed (it will if and only if `Using filesort` appears in the `Extra` column).
- > Will it make sense to make values a part of composite index if they are not too big, e.g. just numbers?

  If you actually want sorted results, then (as indicated above) you will probably find that data retrieval is faster with a covering index; of course, the tradeoff is that insertion/updates will be slower.  What "makes sense" in your case will depend upon the specifics of your application.

  Always remember Knuth's maxim: "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil.*"  I'd probably start *without* a covering index, and only add one if performance degrades to the point it becomes necessary.
- > Will `SELECT key, value FROM MyTable WHERE key > key1 LIMIT 1;` return the next key greater then key1, or any key greater than key1? How to reliably get LT,LE,GT,GE point queries?

  `LIMIT` is applied after the resultset is sorted (if at all).  As explained under the first bullet above, without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause results are returned in an undefined order; thus all that can be said about the single record that will be selected by your query is that it relates to "an indeterminate key that is greater than `key1`".

  To obtain the *next* key greater than `key1`, you must add an explicit `ORDER BY` clause:

  ```
  SELECT key, value FROM MyTable WHERE key > key1 ORDER BY key LIMIT 1
  ```

  For "less than" queries, you must obviously reverse the sort order—e.g.:

  ```
  SELECT key, value FROM MyTable WHERE key <= key1 ORDER BY key DESC LIMIT 1
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I need correctness first - to get values always sorted by key (I have updated question and added another subquestion - could you comment on the 4th one please?). At the same time, I do not want to do something stupid so that during the query the existing order of B-tree is ruined and I will have to re-apply ORDER BY with its overheads. This mock for design-time mainly, but data volume is not that big yet and MySQL could be enough for a long time, I just need to hide storage behind an interface and get exactly the same behavior as plain B-tree. Oddly, MySQL hides it.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! Just out of curiosity: for the 4th point, do you think that, e.g. InnoDB, optimizer is smart enough to just "do binary search and move next/previous" instead of selecting all greater/less keys then sorting them and then taking the first one? Or EXPLAIN will show this as well?

Comment: @V.B.: See [Optimizing LIMIT Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/limit-optimization.html)—"If you combine `LIMIT row_count` with `ORDER BY`, MySQL ends the sorting as soon as it has found the first `row_count` rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast"..."As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query unless you are using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`."